# iOS - attaching local HTML page to email

Tags: html, ios, email

Is it allowed to attach a local stored HTML page to an email send from my iOS application ??

What is the right mimeType ?

## EDIT

this is my code that DOES NOT work , please poit out where is the problem that prevents attachment of the local html file .

```
-(IBAction)share:(id)sender{


NSString *btn_title = [sender titleForState:(UIControlStateNormal)];

 if ([btn_title isEqualToString: @"fb"] ) {


 }else if ([btn_title isEqualToString: @"tw"]){


 }else if ([btn_title isEqualToString: @"email"]){

     if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
     {
         MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
         mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
         [mailer setSubject:@""];
         NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"", nil];
         [mailer setToRecipients:toRecipients];

         NSString *emailBody = @"";

         NSError * error = nil;
         NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:@"/hamla.html" options: NSMappedRead error: &error];

         [mailer addAttachmentData:htmlData mimeType:@"text/html" fileName:@"hamla"];

         [mailer setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
         [self presentModalViewController:mailer animated:YES];
     }
     else
     {
         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Failure"
                                                         message:@"Your device doesn't support the composer sheet"
                                                        delegate:nil
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                               otherButtonTitles: nil];
         [alert show];
     }
 }
```

}

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Mail cancelled: you cancelled the operation and no email message was queued.");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"Mail saved: you saved the email message in the drafts folder.");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Mail send: the email message is queued in the outbox. It is ready to send.");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Mail failed: the email message was not saved or queued, possibly due to an error.");
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Mail not sent.");
            break;
    }
    // Remove the mail view
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why it would be a problem.

The mimetype is 'text/html'. Have a look here:

http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/mime-types-full

Answer (score 0):

@Shymaa Othman the MIME type u r using is correct.Just need to know have u checked whether u r locating ur html correctly and getting NSData not null..?
If not, try this code before attaching to mail.

```
NSData NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"hamla" ofType:@"html"];

NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile];
```

Answer (score 0):

It works when i setMessageBody with isHTML = YES, plus add text attachment.

```
NSData *stringData = [textBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[mailer addAttachmentData:stringData
                 mimeType:@"text/plain"
                 fileName:@"text_file"];
```